# how to create web forms inside folder asp.net

Tags: asp.net

[image]

i need to create set of web forms inside a folder. when i created like below image masterpage images is not showing in all default pages inside folder.....i want to create web forms like below image and it should inherit all thinks from masterpage...how can i do .thanks...

i am using WOWSlider images.images is not showing in folder web forms // WOWSlider.com –

Comment: _when i created like below image masterpage images is not showing_ Could you please show us how do you reference to the image?

Comment: i am using WOWSlider images.images is not showing in folder web forms // WOWSlider.com –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create webform page anywhere you want inside the same web application. The only difference that each page should have correct path to MasterPage in [MasterPageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.page.masterpagefile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" (other page attributes) %>
```

Comment: i am using WOWSlider images.images is not showing in folder web forms // WOWSlider.com

Comment: You can enable Show All Files in toolbar of Solution explorer. Here is sample where it's located - http://lh6.ggpht.com/-MT2n82Gm9Cg/T_Azc28Gx-I/AAAAAAAAJ4U/h6VgPgPqJrA/Visual-Studio-2012-Solution-Explorer%25255B1%25255D.png?imgmax=800 . And then you can add it to solution.